# "authentication required by wireless network" on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, RTL8821AE

Tags: wireless

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 on my system alongside Windows 10 and I can't seem to connect to my Wifi. It always shows "Authentication required by wireless network" and even if I type in the correct password and click connect it keeps showing this message and I can't connect.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Oh oh, what @Pilot6 meant is you should run the command in your terminal and then copy the output (Ctlr + Shift + c) and paste it here.

Comment: ohh sorry @pilot6 I am new here. I added the output, please try to clarify your instruction  to me, thanks.

Comment: You need to run the command in a terminal and post the result. That will show your wireless adapter. You didn't add the output of the command, you posted the command itself that is obviously useless.

Comment: I added the link of the output in the question

Comment: Now it's better, I posted it a normal way. But I have no idea what is the problem, sry.

Comment: we need chili555 :+

Comment: Please anyone who can help @Rinzwind