# "Authentification required by wireless network" on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, network-manager

I have a slightly different story than the one mentioned in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126719/authentication-required-by-wireless-network-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-rtl8821ae/1247010): I can connect, however, it disconnects randomly after roughly 15 minutes then tries to reconnect, asks me for the password a couple of times (both with the saved password pre-filled), keeps loading for a moment then connects back again, which is a real pain especially when I'm speaking to someone on Discord!

The dialog box has the following message:
**Authentification required by wireless network**
**Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network "*NETWORK_NAME_HERE*"**

I did my research and tried:

- disabling IPv6
- turning off wifi power management
- forgetting the network
- restarting Network Manager
- re-installing Network Manager
- and replacing it with an alternative like WICD

but none of these solutions helped me.

As follows the output of the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0662]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5286 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5286] (rev 01)
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
42: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've been having this same issue on Pop_OS 20.10. Kicks me off my Wi-Fi and asks to authenticate every few minutes. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @slanden I solved this issue by buying a new USB Wifi Adapter, so, I suppose that it was a hardware failure.